# Any non trivial example of bi-idempotent objects in a category?

Tags: category-theory

I'm playing a bit with category theory, and I've noticed that it is actually not rare when an object $C$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to its square $C \times C$.

An object $C$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is therefore called idempotent whenever it is isomorphic to its (categorical) product. Trivial examples are given by the terminal object $1$ of any category, or infinite sets in Sets. One can think of a bit less trivial examples in Grp (say, $C = \displaystyle \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$) or in Rings (say, $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ or even $R^\omega$ for any ring). More interesting examples are given in Fields, where for any prime $p$, one can easily show that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is idempotent.

Call coidempotent the dual of the previous notion. Again, one can easily think of trivial examples.

What I'm actually interested in is some non trivial examples of bi-idempotent objects (both idempotent and coidempotent), in some category where the notion of product and coproduct aren't coinciding. Of course, a strict initial object $0$ is always a bi-idempotent object, and it'll be the same for any idempotent object in a category where finite products and finite coproduct coincides (like any abelian category).

Anyone has any non trivial examples of such objects?

Comment: Infinite sets, assuming AC.

Comment: I gave it already, but its too trivial. Sets is just too "lax"

Comment: The category of fields has no products.

Comment: Sure it does have some. Feel free to write the product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with itself and find that it's given by ... $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Cool example, re: fields.

Comment: Does this question arise from some context, or is it just random wondering?

Comment: Random wondering

Comment: There is an example I just thought about where every object is actually a bi-idempotent: any pose seen as a category. Still, I would like to find a true non trivial example.